# How to select all checked columns ,Using jquery DataTables , multiple checkboxes for a table,

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jquery DataTables for the HTML table with two columns of checkboxes. I am unable to retrieve all checked columns using the standard datable query "table.columns().checkboxes.selected()[0];". I get column undefined error. Is it because I am using different js like jquery.dataTables.min.js and dataTables.checkboxes.min.js?

```
function getSelected(){
        var myTable = $("#myTable").DataTable();

        var selectedIds = myTable.columns().checkboxes.selected()[0];
        console.log(selectedIds)

        selectedIds.forEach(function(selectedId) {
        alert(selectedId);
        });
    }
```

## for table

```
 <table id="myTable" class="display select">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th colspan="2">
                                Notifications
                            </th>                        

                            <th rowspan="3">
                                User ID
                            </th>
                            <th rowspan="3">
                                Last Active (in days)
                            </th>
                            <th rowspan="3">
                                Accepted Jobs
                            </th>
                            <th rowspan="3">
                                Distance (in kms)
                            </th>
                            <th rowspan="3">
                                Job Alert
                            </th>
                            <th rowspan="3">
                                News letter
                            </th>

                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                JA
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                NL
                            </th>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <th></th>
                            <th></th>                    
                        </tr>

                    </thead>

                    <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                                <th>Job Alert</th>
                                <th>Newsletter</th>
                                <th>
                                    User ID
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Last Active (in days)
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Accepted Jobs
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                   Distance (in kms)
                                </th>
                                <th>Job Alert</th>
                                <th>Newsletter</th>
                            </tr>

                    </tfoot>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td> <input class="ja_check">                             
                            </td>
                            <td>  <input class="nl_check">                            
                            </td>
                            <td class="uid" name="uid">
                                100
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                23
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                1000
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                2
                            </td>
                            <td><input class="n_jobalert" id="check" name="check" type="checkbox"><label for="check"><input type="hidden" class="lbljobalert" value="1" /></label></td>

                            <td><input class="n_newsletter" id="check" name="check" type="checkbox"><label for="check"><input type="hidden" class="lblnewsletter" value="0" /></label></td>

                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>                              
                            </td>
                            <td>                              
                            </td>
                            <td class="uid">
                                102
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                23
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                1000
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                2
                            </td>
                            <td><input class="n_jobalert" id="check" name="check" type="checkbox"><label for="check"><input type="hidden" class="lbljobalert" value="0" /></label></td>

                            <td><input class="n_newsletter" id="check" name="check" type="checkbox"><label for="check"><input type="hidden" class="lblnewsletter" value="1" /></label></td>

                       </tr>



                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

getting error for "columns undefined"

Comment: share html of you table.

Comment: @mmushtaq: updated html table info.

Comment: Which `input` need to be checked in your case? As I can see you have four input tags in one row. And you have assigned same `id` to all inputs.